# My computer won't boot and I can't access BIOS settings (screen broken, only HDMI)

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, bios, hdmi

I have an HP 15 NoteBook PC with a broken screen cable and I'm using an HDMI cable plugged with my television in order to use the computer (it's been more than 9 months).

I have two operating systems: Windows 10 and Linux. In order to use Linux I need to open the boot menu and select it. The problem is: I can't see my BIOS Screen (F.42) or boot screen on the HDMI cable.

My idea was to change the default boot configuration from Windows Command Prompt and I've changed it using the `bcdedit` command:

```
bcdedit /set default id_of_linux
```

I've restarted the computer and nothing happens (Computer booted with Windows),
so I came back to the Command Prompt (and made the mistake :) ) I've changed the {bootmgr}’s path
using this command:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Linux\grubx64.efi
```

Now when the computer starts it does not boot either with Windows nor Linux.

I don't know if it’s showing an error message or it’s showing the boot menu.. As long as I cannot see the BIOS screen and boot screen using my HDMI cable, I'm stuck. :(

So please if you know how to solve the problem help me 
or if you want to walk me through the F.42 BIOS settings (and remember that I don't see anything on the screen) that would be better. :)

Comment: One option would be to take out the hard drive, connect it to another computer, and fix up whatever went wrong from this computer.

Comment: i guess that's the only idea left